# Spring Boot Kafka Batch Forwarding

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've configured my consumer to accept messages from a topic in batches. How do I forward it to a new topic?

I want each consumed messages to be forwarded as it's own message. So **X** amount of messages consumed will produce **X** amount of messages.

Here's my current setup:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "input")
@SendTo("output")
public ConsumerRecords consume(ConsumerRecords records) {
  // Do things
  return records;
}
```

And here's the exception thrown:

> org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Is there nothing else in your code?
Where do you use an ArrayList?

Comment: The only other code is configuration through the yaml file

Comment: Show the complete stack trace when asking questions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality is not supported. In any case, you can't send a `ConsumerRecord` to a `Producer`.

This works, though

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "input")
@SendTo("output")
public List<String> consume(List<String> data) {
    return data;
}
```

(where `String` is the type created by your deserializer).

Comment: Will this send 1 message with a list of Strings, or multiple messages with one String in each?

Comment: One record per string.

Comment: Also, not being able to send a ConsumerRecord makes a lot of sense now.